# Gir error when push: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally

Tags: github

I use git to backup my projects and it is usually only me which push changes.
The commands i use to push from local to remote are:
git add ExistingProject.cpp
git commit -m "update"
git push origin main

I have notices that when I add file in the remote repo like test.cpp (in github website), I can't push from local to remote. It gives me this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

(Here is simple example of only main without branches)
but I don't understand why is the error, because I don't change test.cpp file, I only
update ExistingProject.cpp that was already add to remote.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to use:
`git pull`
or:
`git push -f origin main`
and it deleted test.cpp file

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it any place so I thought about put here what i found:

I type: `git pull origin main`
and the file I've created in remote repo appear now on the local
seems like there is no point to add files only to remote - because git intended to work with sync between local and remote